# How large is the immune repetoire and at what age does it finalize?

Tags: immunology

There seems to be a large disconnect between the [Wikipedia's article on the immune effector repetoire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immune_repertoire) and Janeway's Immunobiology 9th Edition, a standard textbook widely used to teach immunology to pre-meds. In the Wikipedia it puts the size of the repetoire at 100,000 unique receptors, but in Janeways it says the repetoire has typically 10^8 or between 100 million and 1 billion receptors. Also, in Janeways it implies that the repetoire is largely finalized at some point, although it gives no specific age, but in the Wikpedia article it claims that new T cells are constantly developed by the body throughout a person's lifetime.

How many unique T-cell receptors typically circulate in the body at one time and at what age is the immune repetoire largely decided (if any)?